# How to set a default font and font size in a Sharepoint list?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have made a Sharepoint list. When i create a new item. In the textbox appears the font and fontsize **Calibri  + 11** as default.

[image]

But when i click on the 3 dots and choose the item to erase the formatting of the font. It sets the font to Segoe UI and an empty fontsize. How can I set this as default. So that when a user insert a new row in the list that the textbox has font Segoe UI and fontsize 12 as default.

Greetings, Peter

Greetings, t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no setting that lets you change default font for the WYSIWYG editors.

Comment: What about JSON code for the column Multiple Lines?